# Pinescript multiple pair screener alert indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

`your text`I'm writing a pine script v5 indicator to screen multiple pairs and provide alert if the conditions meet.
The issue I'm facing is sometimes alert is showing the correct but sometimes it's not showing correctly.
e.g I set the alert at EURUSD chart for the indicator.
Based on the symbol I chose in the list it should show alert such as
EIGHTCAP:EURAUD, EIGHTCAP:EURGBP etc but sometimes it just return EURUSD without broker name.

The followings are my logic.

```
//functions to calculate trend and signal
f_ematrend() =>
    -> EMA logic and comparison then return trend as below
    [_stuptrend, _ituptrend, _ltuptrend]

f_bollinger() =>
    -> BB logic and comparison then return signals as below
    [_legend_strongbuy, _legend_strongsell, _legend_buy, _legend_sell, _legend_hammer, _legend_star]

//call functions and return signals
f_screener() =>
    [_stuptrend, _ituptrend, _ltuptrend] = f_ematrend()
    [_legend_strongbuy, _legend_strongsell, _legend_buy, _legend_sell, _legend_hammer, _legend_star] = f_bollinger()
    [_stuptrend, _ituptrend, _ltuptrend, _legend_strongbuy, _legend_strongsell, _legend_buy, _legend_sell, _legend_hammer, _legend_star]

//use request.security to call other security data and get signals then set alerts if criterias are met 
f_screeneralerts(ticker) => 
    [_stuptrend, _ituptrend, _ltuptrend, _legend_strongbuy, _legend_strongsell, _legend_buy, _legend_sell, _legend_hammer, _legend_star] = request.security(ticker, timeframe.period, f_screener())
    -> set alerts based on signals

//pass securities into function
f_screeneralerts(asset_01)
f_screeneralerts(asset_02)
f_screeneralerts(asset_03) etc
```

Please check the following screenshot. The alert without broker prefix are incorrect alert.
[Sample of alert screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obzti.png)

Pinescript alert intermittently triggering incorrectly for multiple securities, multiple timeframes indicator